# .tag on slider not changing the alpha of imagview

Tags: swift, uibutton, tags, slider, alpha

My swift code below has 2 different buttons which should effect the slider baised on the .tagnumber they initialize. B1 should effect the alhpa or transpency of the imageivew and b2 should decrease / increase the size. What b2 does works. What B1 does not work.My code does not use any storyboards. Also the uislider should only do one task it cannont resize the imageview and change the alpha at the same time. Only 1 task.

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var pzc = UIImageView()
var s = UISlider()
var b1 = UIButton()
var b2 = UIButton()
var jessicaAlba:Float = 50
var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var trailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [pzc,s,b1,b2].forEach {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview($0)
    }

    [b1,b2].forEach {
        $0.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    }

    pzc.backgroundColor = .systemGray


    b1.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y+200, width: 30, height: 30)
    b2.frame = CGRect(x: view.center.x-115, y: view.center.y+250, width: 30, height: 30)

    s.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .touchUpInside)
    b1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mr1), for: .touchUpInside)
    b2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mr2), for: .touchUpInside)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
        b1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :37.5),
        b1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 225),
        b1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75),
        b1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

        b2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :130),
        b2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 225),
        b2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75),
        b2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    ])

    s.minimumValue = 50
    s.maximumValue = 200
    s.setValue(jessicaAlba, animated: false)

    view.addSubview(s)

    s.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    s.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    s.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

    pzc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(pzc)

    topConstraint = pzc.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: CGFloat(jessicaAlba))
    topConstraint.isActive = true
    heightConstraint = pzc.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor , multiplier: 0.5, constant: CGFloat(-jessicaAlba))
    heightConstraint.isActive = true

    leadingConstraint = pzc.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(jessicaAlba))
    leadingConstraint.isActive = true
    trailingConstraint = pzc.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(-jessicaAlba))
    trailingConstraint.isActive = true


}



    @objc func moveRight() {
        if s.tag == 1 {
            pzc.alpha = CGFloat(s.value)
        }
        if s.tag == 2 {
            changeSize()
        }
    }
@objc func changeSize() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.jessicaAlba = self.s.value
        self.topConstraint.constant = CGFloat(self.jessicaAlba)
        self.heightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(-self.jessicaAlba)
        self.leadingConstraint.constant = CGFloat(self.jessicaAlba)
        self.trailingConstraint.constant = CGFloat(-self.jessicaAlba)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (finished) in
    }
}



@objc func mr1() {
    b1.backgroundColor = .brown
    b2.backgroundColor = .systemPink


    s.tag = 1
}
@objc func mr2() {

      b2.backgroundColor = .brown
      b1.backgroundColor = .systemPink
      s.tag = 2
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here multiple target are added on your UISlider. Just modify your function.

```
@objc func moveRight() {
    if s.tag == 1 {
        let diff = s.maximumValue-s.minimumValue
        pzc.alpha = CGFloat(s.value/diff)
    }
    if s.tag == 2 {
        changeSize()
    }
}
```

You can also modify your changeSize() function for animation.

```
@objc func changeSize() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.jessicaAlba = self.s.value
        self.topConstraint.constant = CGFloat(self.jessicaAlba)
        self.heightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(-self.jessicaAlba)
        self.leadingConstraint.constant = CGFloat(self.jessicaAlba)
        self.trailingConstraint.constant = CGFloat(-self.jessicaAlba)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (finished) in
    }
}
```

Comment: edited my code above with your code not seeing any affect on the alpha but the animation works.

Comment: s.value is bigger than alpha range. you can modify with, let diff = s.maximumValue-s.minimumValue pzc.alpha = CGFloat(s.value/diff)